# How to select not commented rows?

Tags: linux, bash, comments, grep

I have file that contains:

```
# sdfdsfds fsf
var1=1232
#fdsfdsfds
#fdsfsdf
var2=456
..................
```

I need select only not commented rows - that not start from #
Does it possible with grep?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-E` option for regex and `-v` option for inverse matching.

```
grep -v -E '^#' file
```

Answer (score 5):

use the `-v`(invert-match) option in `grep`:

```
$ grep -v '^#' file.txt
var1=1232
var2=456
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will do it:

```
grep -v ^# file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `grep -v '^#'`

The `-v` option is for **not** logic.